# Best Method to test Opened Ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, telnet, dmz, amazon-vpc

We have a requirment where in we have to test 500+ Port opening rules. So requires a suggest on below points.

- Which is the best tool to test the connectivity of the ports. Telnet will be sufficient
- If there is no application is listening to a port will telnet be getting a resposne from the port.

We are checking it in Amazon VPC against Security Groups.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From within the machine `netstat -ntlp` / `netstat -nulp` will show all open TCP / UDP ports (and associated programs) respectively.

From external, `nmap -sT` and `nmap -sU` will show open TCP/UDP ports respectively.

Keep in mind that these commands might require root privileges and also make sure to whitelist the source of the scans in the firewall - or else you might find yourself locked out, if the host is using something like fail2ban.

Comment: netstat shows the open ports on one server I run from it right..? I would like to check the connectivity across servers.

Comment: use nc then - you can script it using bash - check before installing nmap as it might not be allowed from your administrators ...

Comment: That is helpful I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at nmap (http://nmap.org).
it can do many types of scans and is avaulable for many oses.
There is also a windows version and gui

Answer (score 1):

You can use nmap to test a port (or list of ports) on a host (or list of hosts). Example:

```
nmap 192.168.0.101-150 -p 22,80,443
```

checks three ports on each of 150 hosts and produces a nicely-formatted report. If there is no program listening at a port, nmap will show the port as "closed". The port will be shown as "filtered" if a firewall is preventing access to it from the testing computer.

You can do the same scan and produce a report with one host per line, suitable for grepping or importing to another program:

```
nmap 192.168.0.101-150 -p 22,80,443 -oG -
```

(Note the final - in the line above for output to stdout. Change to a filename if desired.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use nc (netcat) for scanning any tcp or udp ports.

> The nc (or netcat) utility is used for just about anything under the
>   sun involving TCP or UDP.  It can open TCP connections, send UDP
>   packets,
>        listen on arbitrary TCP and UDP ports, do port scanning, and deal with both IPv4 and IPv6.  Unlike telnet(1), nc scripts nicely, and
>   separates
>        error messages onto standard error instead of sending them to standard output, as telnet(1) does with some.

Basicly,

```
nc -z -wX <host> <port>
```

-z

> Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without
>   sending any data to them.  It is an error to use this option in con-
>                junction with the -l option.A more compact way to use it:

-w3

> If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then
>   the connection is silently closed.  The -w flag has no effect on
>                the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection, with or without the -w flag.  The default is no timeout.

For example;

```
nc -z -w3 example.com 22
```

Will scan port 22 on example.com without sending any data and timeout will be 3 seconds.